# Syntax error ++ expected?

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error

So I'm doing a project for school using Eclipse. I keep getting a Syntax Error on token "+",++ expected.

```
System.out.print ("End of Supplier transactions");
calcsuppliersummary();
System.out.print("The total interest of"+name+"is:" +interest+);
System.out.print("The supplier Ending Balance is:"+endbal+ );
}
```

The error shows up at the System.out.print line.

Comment: Remove + at end.

Comment: To be specific, remove the + at the end of interest and endbal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` at the end of the `interest` and `endbal` makes the compiler think that something will be added afterwards. If it's the end of what you want to print, you don't need the `+` at the end. Just like you wouldn't write 2+2+=4 (but you'd write 2+2=4), you'd write `"The supplier Ending Balance is:"+endbal` instead of `"The supplier Ending Balance is:"+endbal+`.

Hope this helps!

By the way, are you new to Java? If so, there's some really great books out there that make it really easy to learn :).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks that worked out great. Yeah I'm new to java, currently trying to use the textbook issued with the class, which doesn't seem to have almost anything right in it. Do you have any books that you can recommend? I'm currently just using the oracle site.

Comment: Sorry, I actually focus on C#, but I think a quick Amazon or eBay (or even Youtube) search for Java tutorials will help tremendously.